# Value cannot be null. Parameter name entity

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to delete using Ajax. When I press the Delete button, an exception occurs:
`Value cannot be null. Parameter name entity.`

The controller code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult DeleteCar(int? Id)
{
    var cardetail = car.Cars.Find(Id);
    return View(cardetail);
}

public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int? Carid)
{
    Car cardetail = car.Cars.Find(Carid);
    car.Cars.Remove(cardetail);
    car.SaveChanges();
    return Content("Success");
}
```

The Ajax code of delete as follows.

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteStd', function () {
    //  alert();
    var Carid = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/Home/DeleteConfirmed?Carid=" + Carid,
        ajaxasync: true,
        success: function () {
            alert("Record delete successfully");
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.x);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like no entity was returned from the Find call with the id provided. Where are you populating `Carid` on the client side?

Comment: Why do you allow `null` values for the argument to the `DeleteCar` and `DeleteConfirmed` methods? Also, you may need to verify that `cardetail` is not `null` before trying to remove it.

Comment: `var Studentid = $(this).attr('id');` - should that be `CarId`?